# python 2.7 image error in tkinter library

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, arcgis, arcpy

I use python 2.7 to create a graphical interface with Tkinter (for an arcgis script) but when I want to load wallpaper in the interface, it gives me the error
"_tkinter.TclError: could not recognize data in image file [path to image]"
I searched the internet for various solutions and the best one would be with the PIL library.
Can't find another solution?
Below is the written code. Thanks

```
from Tkinter import * 
import os

ROOT_PATH = os.getcwd()
window = Tk()
window.title("Update TXT field")
window.geometry("950x350")
window.config(bg = "white")

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 900, height = 350, bg = "white")
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 1)


img = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "logo.png"))
image = canvas.create_image(861,320, image=img)
canvas.pack()

label_path = Label(text = "Add path to folder:")
label_path.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

path_entry = Entry(width = 35)
path_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

button = Button()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This means the data in the .png file is not actually png. Did you take a file in some other format and just rename it to .png?

Comment: I downloaded the image from the internet and that was its format, .png. I did not change the image extension

Comment: What tkinter version do you use? Because PhotoImage supports PNG format since 8.6

Comment: It looks like you're using python 2.x, that version may not support png. You should consider upgrading to python 3.x, the 2.x version was [sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) a couple years ago.

Comment: @Robert Mihai Nicolescu.  Your code will work in Python 3.11.0b3. If you upgrading, it will take about at least 2 minutes. And then run your code. BINGO :).  Btw, the lower capital t will be tkinter instead of Tkinter for rest of the  Python3.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 for arcpy library at work and now I want to upgrade my scripts, with GUI interface. Thanks  a lot for the answers, guys!